# Paypal doDirectPayment in live mode generating error 10501 : Invalid Configuration

Tags: paypal

I've implemented paypal doDirectPayment  on a website. For Sandbox Testing it run properly But For Live mode it generate error

> L_ERRORCODE0 - 10501
>
> L_SHORTMESSAGE0  - Invalid Configuration
>
> L_LONGMESSAGE0  - This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.

From Paypal DirectPayment API Errors and Warnings, I got Corrective Action

> Occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.

But i'don't know how to enable this billing agreement

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you applied for Payments Pro already and gotten it approved/enabled on your account?  If so, when it's first approved you should get emails for accepting the billing agreement, and it would also pop up on your overview page when you login to PayPal.

Another cause of this is that you are approved for Payments Pro PayFlow edition, in which case you would need to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment in order to process credit cards.

If you're on the newest Payments Pro 2.0 you should have full access to both PayFlow and DDP, however, sometimes you have to get them to enable DDP for you.

So the first thing you need to figure out is which version of Pro you got signed up with and then I can help you more.

Comment: Hi Sir, Firstly Thanks for reply. i have one another query , Could you tell me what is payment pro 2.0 and how we trace it. sorry if it is silly question , but really i don't know about it. i read term payment pro only and aware about it. Thanks

Comment: Did they give you an account at http://manager.paypal.com where you sign in with a partner, vendor, user, and password?